# Boost regex crashed, solution was DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES

Tags: regex, macos, boost, cmake

I've compiled a code on Mac using cmake that makes use of Boost. When the source code is built and executed, it crashes my application with this error:

```
CRASHED in boost::re_detail::basic_regex_parser<char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::parse_extended
```

The only solution I could find was preloading Boost regex before launching the application so I had to use DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES and give it the path of libboost_regex.dylib

So far the application is working, but I'm wondering if there is any way I can fix it in the source code of the app. Is there any OSX specific flag I'm supposed to put inside the cmakelist file?

Note that, this tool works completely fine on Windows and Linux when built in those OS', it's just on Mac it's having many issues.